# Add a new calendar to an EKEventStore with EventKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, eventkit

How can I add a Calendar (not an event) to a EKEventStore in iOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I caught an exception unless I also did:

```
// Get the calendar source
EKSource* localSource;
for (EKSource* source in eventStore.sources) {
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
    {
        localSource = source;
        break;
    }
}

if (!localSource)
    return;

calendar = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:eventStore];
calendar.source = localSource;
```

Naturally, take a look at the other EKSourceType enums to see which one is appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
EKEventStore *calendarStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKCalendar *calendar = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:calendarStore];
NSString *calendarID = [calendar calendarIdentifier]; /// cache this in your app data for retrieval later


[calendar setTitle:@"New Calendar"];

NSError *error = nil;

BOOL saved = [calendarStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];

if (!saved) {
    // handle error....

}
```

Comment: saving without a source results in an error

Comment: all this only adds a calendar which cannot be seen from the default calendar app for me. did anyone face a similar issue?
is there something I may have missed..or have to add?