# iOS EKEventStore event saving in default calendar but not in other custom Calendar

Tags: ios, nscalendar, ekevent, ekeventstore

I am using BOOL method to save event in my custom Calendar and `strForCalanderID` have `calendarIdentifier` value but that event is not save in particular calendar. It's working fine when I am adding event on default calendar but not in custom or user created calendar.

```
-(BOOL)addEventOnICal:(NSMutableDictionary*)eventDict{
EKCalendar *calendar = nil;
    NSString *calendarIdentifier =strForCalanderID;//strForCalanderID=> custom Calendar identifier

    if (calendarIdentifier) {
        calendar = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:calendarIdentifier];
        calendar.title=strForCalanderName;
    }
    if (!calendar) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945537/add-a-new-calendar-to-an-ekeventstore-with-eventkit
        calendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:eventStore];


        for (EKSource *s in eventStore.sources) {
            if (s.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal) {
                calendar.source = s;
                break;
            }
        }
        NSString *calendarIdentifier = [calendar calendarIdentifier];
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL saved = [eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];
        if (saved) {
        } else {
            // unable to save calendar
            return NO;
        }
    }
    // this shouldn't happen
    if (!calendar) {
        return NO;
    }
    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    event.location = @"Indore";
    event.title = @"Hello Test";
    // set the start date to the current date/time and the event duration to two hours
    event.startDate = StartDate;
    event.endDate = EndDate;


    NSError *error = nil;
    // save event to the callendar
    BOOL result = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
    if (result) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        // NSLog(@"Error saving event: %@", error);
        // unable to save event to the calendar
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid calendar? I had a similar issue where I opened a calendar but when used shortly afterwards was nil. I have managed to get it working reliably by using manager singleton class that keeps assigns the calendar to a property. Suggest breakpoints in the above and confirm everything is OK prior to saveEvent call.